# Extract IPTC-Keywords Longer than 64 Chars in Java

Tags: java, adobe, metadata, metadata-extractor

I'm using [Drews Metadata Extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) for Java to extract IPTC-keywords from a JPEG Image. Works good so far.
I assigned the keywords using Adobe Bridge. Unfortunately, Bridge supports keywords longer than 64 chars but the metadata extractor library only reads the first 64 chars of the String.
Are there any ideas of how to read the whole keyword? (max. 128 chars)

PS: It's not possible to shorten the Keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sample image I can test this with, I'll give it a shot. You can open your image in a hex editor too and see whether the full text is present. If the library is truncating it, I'd like to see if we can avoid that.

Please [file an issue](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues) that includes a sample image.

**EDIT** I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948554/24874) that Bridge is correctly truncating the keyword to 64-bytes for IPTC data, but it seems likely that the full string is available via XMP.